# Windows server 2008, Dns. I'm confused

Tags: domain-name-system, web-hosting, windows-server-2008-r2

I recently setup a window server 2008 server at work. Keep in mind I have never worked with it before:).

Background story is I try to host a couple of sites on the server through iis7, I got domains (currently hosted at other hosters for the moment). I want to point the domain NS to my server on all of them.

I have read how to setup a DNS on the server, so far so good. now my dns is *companyname.com*

in the server manager I got DNS / *companyname.com*
in there I got ns.comanyname.com,
 in there I got Host(A) with the server ip

now this is where I get confused about how things work with DNS, NS & Host(A). I dont know how to assign(so to speak) the Host(A) to one of my webapps hosted on the iis7, because that is the pointer right?. To leave an example to work with lets say, Hosted.com is hosted on my iis7, on port 81.

You don't understand how great full I would be if somebody could explain this confusion.

**EDIT:** Do I need to create a DNS for every site hosted on my server? Or just make a A Host/Record?

Thanks guys

Comment: check out http://serverfault.com/questions/113445/dns-resolution-order-of-operations/113455 and http://serverfault.com/questions/82761/why-does-my-registrar-only-want-name-server-names/82763 and http://serverfault.com/questions/64892/dns-failure-domain-control-panel-only-accepts-url-as-dns

Comment: I think what I was looking for in this case is virtual hosting, host multiple sites on one ip. Sorry if the question was not clear enof.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to ask/inform your REGISTRAR (where you bought the domain name) of your new NS server for your own DNS to be the actual DNS used by clients trying to reach your hosts.

Your registrar is the authority asked for the NS records, the nameservers that have authority on your zone (company.com for example). Then, your nameservers are asked for a particular host (www.companyname.com for example) as a A record for a web server for example.

Comment: Be aware that the RFC specifies that 2 NS should be available for your domains, so your registrar might ask you 2 public IPs for those.

Comment: Yes I am aware of the NS & IP's. I don't really get what you mean with the last part of your post Alexandre. Do I need to create a DNS for every site hosted on my server? Or just make a A Host/Record?

Comment: Yes, just create a new A record for each site you want to host, all refering to the same IP if you want to host multiple sites on one single web server.